# Replace specific word in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div

```
<div id="divTest" contenteditable="true">
```

I need to get the last word from caret position and on certain condition I have to test and remove this specific word only. Below is how am I doing

```
$('#divTest').on('keyup focus', function (e) {
           if (e.keyCode == 32) {
               var lastWord = getWordPrecedingCaret(this),                                       spanLastWord = $('#lastWord');

           }
       });

function getWordPrecedingCaret(containerEl) {
               var preceding = "",
                                    sel,
                                    range,
                                    precedingRange;
               if (window.getSelection) {
                   sel = window.getSelection();
                   if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
                       range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
                       range.collapse(true);
                       range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
                       preceding = range.toString();


                   }
               } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
                   range = sel.createRange();
                   precedingRange = range.duplicate();
                   precedingRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
                   precedingRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
                   preceding = precedingRange.text;
               }

               var words = range.toString().trim().split(' '),
                        lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
                  if (lastWord) {

                   var resultValue = 'some'; // this value is coming from some other function
                   if (resultValue == lastWord) {
                     alert('do nothing');
                       // do nothing
                   }
                 else
                   {
                     alert('replace word');
                     // delete That specific word and replace if with resultValue
                   }
                   return lastWord;

               }
           }
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogzpXV

I have tried range.deleteContents(); but that will delete all the content in the div.
How can I replace specific word only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To work with [`Ranges`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) we need to keep in mind that we are working with Nodes, not only the text that is rendered. The structure you want to manipulate is:

```
<div id="divTest" contenteditable="true"> <-- Element Node
    "some text" <-- TextNode
</div>
```

But it also could be:

```
<div id="divTest" contenteditable="true"> <-- Element Node
    "some text" <-- TextNode
    "more text" <-- TextNode
    "" <-- TextNode
</div>
```

To solve your problem is simplier to handle only one `TextNode`, I propose to use the [`normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.normalize) function to join all of them into a single one.

Then you only need to set the `Range` to the word's bounds before [`deleteContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range.deleteContents). Once deleted, you can insert a new `TextNode` with the substitution using [`insertNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range.insertNode).

```
var wordStart = range.toString().lastIndexOf(lastWord);
var wordEnd = wordStart + lastWord.length;

/* containerEl.firstChild refers to the div's TextNode */                   
range.setStart(containerEl.firstChild, wordStart);
range.setEnd(containerEl.firstChild, wordEnd);
range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(resultValue));
```

For this to work, you need that the text is in a single `TextNode`. But after `ìnsertNode` the `div` will contain multiple text nodes. To fix this simply call [`normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.normalize) to join all `TextNode` elements.

```
containerEl.normalize();
```

**Edit:**

As Basj points out, the original solution fails for multiline. That's because when hitting ENTER the structure changes from:

```
<div id="divTest" contenteditable="true"> <-- Element Node
    "some text" <-- TextNode
</div>
```

to something like:

```
<div id="divTest" contenteditable="true"> <-- Element Node
    <div>"some text"</div>
    <div>"more text"</div>
</div>
```

I've updated this answer, but it's also worth to read [Basj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50826185/3963330) at this question: [Replace word before cursor, when multiple lines in contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817526/replace-word-before-cursor-when-multiple-lines-in-contenteditable)

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j3vp41c0/96/) or runnable code snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('divTest').onkeyup = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        getWordPrecedingCaret(this);
    }
};

function getWordPrecedingCaret(containerEl) {
    var preceding = "",
        sel,
        range,
        precedingRange;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
            preceding = range.toString();
        }
    } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        range = sel.createRange();
        precedingRange = range.duplicate();
        precedingRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        precedingRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
        preceding = precedingRange.text;
    }

    var words = range.toString().trim().split(' '),
        lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
        
    if (lastWord) {
        var resultValue = 'some'; // this value is coming from some other function
        if (resultValue == lastWord) {
            console.log('do nothing: ' + lastWord);
            // do nothing
        } else {
            console.log('replace word ' + lastWord);
            
            /* Find word start and end */
            var wordStart = range.endContainer.data.lastIndexOf(lastWord);
            var wordEnd = wordStart + lastWord.length;
            console.log("pos: (" + wordStart + ", " + wordEnd + ")");
                           
            range.setStart(range.endContainer, wordStart);
            range.setEnd(range.endContainer, wordEnd);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(resultValue));
            // delete That specific word and replace if with resultValue

            /* Merge multiple text nodes */            
            containerEl.normalize();
        }
        return lastWord;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="divTest" contenteditable="true">Write words here and hit SPACE BAR</div>
```

Comment: I've added some css in order to highlight the editable div (it was transparent). It should work at least in FF and Chrome. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: If you add multiple lines and hit SPACE, it doesn't work anymore. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50826336/1422096).

Comment: I've edited the answer and added a reference to your solution. Thanks.

Comment: im getting error at this line 
range.endContainer.data undefined
NotesPage.html:98 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastIndexOf' of undefined

Answer (score 4):

```
 words = ['oele', 'geel', 'politie', 'foo bar'];

function markWords() {
    var html = div.html().replace(/<\/?strong>/gi, ''),
        text = html.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
        exp;
    $.each(words, function(i, word) {
        exp = new RegExp('\\b(' + word + ')\\b', 'gi');
        html = html.replace(exp, function(m) {
console.log('WORD MATCH:', m);
            return '<strong>' + m + '</strong>';
        });
    });
    //html = html.replace('&nbsp;', ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
console.log('HTML:', html);
console.log('----');
    div.html(html);
}
```

Call this function on `setinterval`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nebgcpzz/)**

Comment: it is going to replace each word within the contenteditable with the replacement word, right? 
Let say, I have text like this "Test one Test two Test | Three Test"
Now because my cursor is before Three so I want to replace only that Test word.

Answer (score 1):

Tobías' solution works well for single-line `contenteditable` div. But if you add multiple lines, it doesn't work anymore.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50826185/1422096) is a general solution that works for both single-line or multiline contenteditable div.