# Replace word before cursor, when multiple lines in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I want to replace the word before cursor in `contenteditable` div (see also [Detect the last written word when typing TAB in a textarea or contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794324/detect-the-last-written-word-when-typing-tab-in-a-textarea-or-contenteditable-di)).

The following code:

1. totally works for the first paragraph of the `contenteditable` div
2. does not work for the next paragraphs of the `contenteditable` div:

   > Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': The offset 71 is larger than the node's length (38).

**How should I modify the following code to make it work when pressing TAB in the 2nd line of the `contenteditable` div?**

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var elt = e.target;
    if (elt.isContentEditable)
    {        
        if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            elt.focus();
            range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.setStart(elt, 0);
            var words = range.toString().trim().split(' ');
            var lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
            if (lastWord) {
                var wordStart = range.toString().lastIndexOf(lastWord);
                var wordEnd = wordStart + lastWord.length;
                range.setStart(elt.firstChild, wordStart);
                range.setEnd(elt.firstChild, wordEnd);
                range.deleteContents();
                document.execCommand('insertText', false, "hello\nnewline");
                elt.normalize();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable>Hello, click here and press TAB to replace this WORD<br>Also click here and press TAB after this ONE</div>
```

---

Note: I've already tested the answer from [Replace specific word in contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656887/replace-specific-word-in-contenteditable) but it doesn't work when there are multiple lines in the contenteditable div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var elt = e.target;
    if (elt.isContentEditable)
    {        
        if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            elt.focus();
            sel = document.getSelection();
            sel.modify("extend", "backward", "word");
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            console.log(range.toString().trim());
            range.deleteContents();
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = '<b>test</b> and a <a href="hjkh">link</a>';
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node;
            while (node = el.firstChild) {
                frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);
            range.collapse();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable>Hello, press TAB to replace this WORD<br>Also press TAB after this ONE</div>
```

This is a [full solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50817299) for both `textarea` and contenteditable `div`.